# $\int \frac{2x^7+3x^2}{x^{10}-2x^{5}+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{2x^7+3x^2}{x^{10}-2x^{5}+1}dx$$

I have no idea how to approach this problem.

I just know that I have to express the top expression in some form of a derivative of the expression in the denominator. But I just couldn't figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the denomenator is $(x^5 - 1)^2$, then you know the roots, and if you know what partial fractions are then you can break down the integrad into these. By the there are complex roots.

Comment: @Physor there is a more elegant solution by forcing chain rule to appear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the expression as

$$\int\frac{2x^7+3x^2}{(x^5-1)^2}dx = \int \frac{2x+\frac{3}{x^4}}{\left(x^2-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2}dx = \frac{-1}{x^2-\frac{1}{x^3}}+C $$

by dividing top and bottom by $x^6$